# variable always storing null value in datagridview

Tags: c#, variables, datagridview, cell

I want to store the cell value of the `DataGridView` control, but this variable is always storing null values, whether or not the cell contains a value.

```
var cellValue = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
```

If I do the following:

```
string cellValue = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() ;
```

it produces the error:

> NullRefrenceException was unhandled .

I used it in various events like `CellEndEdit`, `CellValidating`, `CellLeave`, but the result is the same. What should I do to save the correct value in hte cell including null also (ie. if any cell is empty).

Answer (score 1):

The error is happening because you're calling `ToString()` on a `null` object. The solution is to test it for `null` first, and then do something different if it's `null`:

```
var actualCellValue = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;

// Choose a default value in case it's null (string.Empty or null)
string cellValue = string.Empty; 

// Test the value for null, and if it isn't, call ToString() on it
if (actualCellValue != null) cellValue = actualCellValue.ToString();
```

A shorter way to write this logic is:

```
string cellValue = (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value == null)
    : string.Empty // or null, depending on how you want to store null values
    ? dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
```